# Select class in selenium webdriver is not working for dropdown

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing automation script for website and I am stuck with dropdown. Checked with all available solutions but no use. Please find below code snippet and html content for select tag. If any solution will help me to unblock from this.

Html content:

```
<select id="Adults" class="span span15" tabindex="8" name="adults" size="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

Java code:

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//select[@id='Adults']")
    private WebElement adultsDropDown;

    public SearchFlightRoundTrip(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void selAdults(String text) {
            Select selectAdults = new Select(adultsDropDown);
            selectAdults.selectByVisibleText(text);
    }

    @Test
    public void selNumAdults() {
        searchFlight.selAdults("2");
    }
```

Above script runs without any error or exception but does not perform selection in dropdown.

Comment: Did you try `selectByIndex`?

Comment: I tried selectByIndex and selectByValue but dint worked.

Comment: Try to use `getOptions()` and print it out to console in `for` loop. We'll see if Selenium finds these options in the first place

Comment: Please apply some kind of `wait` to actually let the operation happen.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski, used getOptions method to print text. Its printing  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  instead of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. Please find my code below. List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();
  int size = list.size();

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   String values = list.get(i).getText();
   System.out.println(values);
  }

Comment: I would try demouser123's approach. Try do add sleeps between select operations and if that helps - convert them to `ExpectedConditions`

Try:
public void selAdults(String text) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Select selectAdults = new Select(adultsDropDown);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                selectAdults.selectByVisibleText(text);
           catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

Comment: @RafałLaskowski, tried with above approach but still its not working.

Comment: According to your comment _Its printing 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8_, I think there are 2 dropdowns. Can you click at the select? `adultsDropDown.click();`

Comment: @Buaban, able to click and after clicking dropdown lists are displayed.

Comment: @BhanuPrakash What do you mean by `not working` and `I am stucked with dropdown`? What are your exact manual steps? Where are you stuck? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB, Not working means selenium script is not selecting value from dropdown list and not throwing any exception also. I am stucked with this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

selectAdults.selectByVisibleText("text");

text should be in double quotes

selectAdults.selectByVisibleText("2")

Comment: Can you explain why `text` should be quoted? It looks like a `String` argument passed to the `selAdults` function, to me.